# Block View limited by node, where node path is only part of the entire URL

Tags: views

This may be a bit hard to explain. I have nodes at something/node-title. I then want particular blocks to show up on any pages deeper (such as something/node-title/deeper or something/node-title/deeper/even-deeper), but to use the contextual filter based on the something/node-title node.

If I was ONLY doing those blocks on something/node-title, it's simple. I use the Content: nid contextual filter, and set default value as content ID from URL. But, since I only want to use a partial URL, I can't do that.

I tried to choose "Raw value from url" instead of "Content ID from url", and set the index value as 2, but that didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The nid is the argument, regardless of the URL alias. It is always in the same spot, unless you have custom routes of some kind. 'something/node-title' is for example, node/123, where 'something/node-title/deeper' is node/456 - the argument still works because it isn't the alias that matters unless you are talking visibility.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying in this context, but I'm not sure if/how it helps. Sorry. :-/ I realize that the full URL will always resolve itself to the specific node/nid that it corresponds to. I'm just trying to figure out if I can use only a portion of the URL instead.